# Save file in sql server

Tags: sql-server, grails

I'm migration oracle to sql server, I have this domain:

```
class HDocument implements Serializable{
  byte[] document
  String name

  static constraints = {
    document(maxSize: 50000000)
  }

  static mapping = {
    if (CH.config.database == "ORACLE") {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'hDocument_id']
    }
    document sqlType:'blob'
    version false
  }
}
```

In oracle work but in sql server when i start the tool, dont create this table, i think the issue is in : document sqlType:'blob'